# Chaining a method only if a value exists (js)

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I want to chain on an additional method only if a value exists.

This is for a node/express powered rest api. It should filter the results returned only if a query string is provided for the thing that users want to be filtered. E.g. index/tasks?completed=true should return all completed tasks whereas index/tasks should just return all tasks. I can just setup an if else statement to check if the query string exists or not and then duplicate the find call with all the additional settings chained on but it seems like a bad way of doing things. Would be a nice if there was a way more like the uncommented code.

The commented code is fine and works

```
//nice if it works
var tasks = await Task.find({owner: req.user._id})
    .if(req.query.completed){
        .where({completed: req.query.completed})
}
.limit(parseInt(req.query.limit))
.skip(parseInt(req.query.skip))
.sort(ascending+field)




//works
    // if(req.query.completed){
    //     var tasks = await Task.find({owner: req.user._id})
    //     .where({completed: req.query.completed})
    //     .limit(parseInt(req.query.limit))
    //     .skip(parseInt(req.query.skip))
    //     .sort(ascending+field)
    // }else{
    //     tasks = await Task.find({owner: req.user._id}) 
    //     .limit(parseInt(req.query.limit))
    //     .skip(parseInt(req.query.skip))
    //     .sort(ascending+field)
    // }


//check there were tasks and send it off
        if(!tasks){
            res.status(404).send()
        }
        res.send(tasks)
```

Is there a way to do something similar to the `//nice if it works` code?

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking, but to save you time, take a look at Aggregation Pipelines https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a query object and check if the query string exists then add field to this object.

Example:

```
var query = {owner: req.user._id};
if(req.query.completed) query.completed = req.query.completed;
var tasks = await Task.find(query)
                      .limit(parseInt(req.query.limit))
                      .skip(parseInt(req.query.skip))
                      .sort(ascending+field)
```

Comment: this is pretty much straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

use `RegExp`.

```
if (req.query.completed) {
    var tasks = await Task.find({ owner: req.user._id })
                          .where({ completed: req.query.completed || new RegExp('.*') })
                          .limit(parseInt(req.query.limit))
                          .skip(parseInt(req.query.skip))
                          .sort(ascending+field)
}
```